# intel-xdk: how to delete projects builds created on cloud

Tags: intel-xdk

I just started using `intel XDK` since a week. Its nice working with `intel xdk`. Its build version is build 0277. I created several test projects while learning, several builds were created on cloud. But I didn't find any option for deleting those builds from cloud. Yes, of course, projects could be deleted but not their builds on cloud.

If anyone knows, how to do this, please help me..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can login here: https://appcenter.html5tools-software.intel.com/csd/controlpanel.aspx and delete the projects (click the trash icon for the project you want to delete)

Comment: That link no longer works. You can now access the control panel from here:

https://appcenter.html5tools-software.intel.com/csd/controlpanel.aspx